# Google Cloud Platform Bookshelf tutorial - CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: sql-server

Ran into the following error during the Google Cloud Platform Bookshelf tutorial, when executing the Update-Database command in the Package Manager Console:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the the dbcreator permission to the **dotnetapp** login, but then it created a new database called **DatabaseName**.

Turned out that in the connection string in web.config, I needed to change the Initial Catalog to **bookshelf**, the name of the database.